# Display data from left join query [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

stackers
I'm facing a problem on displaying data from query that contain join statement.

```
public function view(Request $id)
{
    $user_id = $id->input('id');
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('*')
                ->leftjoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                ->leftjoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
                ->where('users.id', '=', $user_id)->get();
    return view('/admin/view_user', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

From the above code, how do i display the row and the join table data from roles, and role_user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This :

```
public function view(Request $id)
{
    $user_id = $id->input('id');
    $users = DB::table('users')
                ->select('users.*','role_user.fieldName','roles.fieldName')
                ->leftjoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
                ->leftjoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
                ->where('users.id', '=', $user_id)->get();
    return view('/admin/view_user', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

Write **tableName.fieldName** to get perticalur table's data in **JOIN** query

Comment: I did try the above code, and it seems to produce an error "Undefined property: stdClass::$roles". this is the code to display an output 
<tr>
                                    <td>{{$users->roles.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$users->email}}</td></tr>

Comment: you can't access value by :{{$users->roles.name}} .

Comment: so how should i do to access the required table column? this is the first time i've played around with Laravel.

Comment: In foreach loop access column one by one by 
ex.
@foreach($users as $user)
<td>{{$user->name}}</td>  
@endforeach

Comment: problem solved, i've had trouble as two tables of roles and users have a similar column name. To overcome this i've renamed the required column, this is the changed part 

"->select('users.*', 'roles.name as r_name')" 

thanks by the way @Yasin Patel you have been very helpful